# load data infile

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to fix that warrning.

[image]

I try with Ignore, but in vain.

```
    create table MEDICI ( id_m int auto_increment primary key, 
                      nume varchar(100) unique,
                      prenume varchar(100) unique,
                      statut enum('Primar','Specialist'),
                      specialitate varchar(50) 
                      );
```

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statement you showed us doesn't seem to have anything to do with the real error, which is being caused by `LOAD DATA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While loading the data to the table, there are two same values **Nutu** exist for column  **prenume**. Column **prenume** is defined as **unique**.

Correct the data and try loading the data into table.